# Call xcopy with parameters?

Tags: python, windows, xcopy

I'm trying to call `xcopy` with `subprocess` which will be equal to bat command.

Every time I get errors: "invalid number of parameters" or "file not found".

How can I do this?

**PYTHON**

```
subprocess.call([
           "xcopy",
           str(C:\appFolder\appFile.txt),
           str(F:\appFolder\appFile.txt),
           "/s /y /q"
        ])
```

**CMD**

```
xcopy "C:\appFolder\appFile.txt" "F:\appFolder\appFile.txt" /s /y /q >nul
```

Comment: You need to specify both path strings one of these ways: `r"С:\appFolder\appFile.txt"` or `"С:\\appFolder\\appFile.txt"` or `"С:/appFolder/appFile.txt"`.

Comment: im getting pathes from the file line by line like "folder\0055338f6552879f.txt"
how can i escape it when path is in the variable?

Comment: An error about invalid number of parameters comes from using slash instead of backslash in the path or from not using quotes. Also, xcopy may prompt to ask whether the target is a file name or a directory name. To avoid that you can append a "*" to the target name. For example: `call('xcopy.exe "%s" "%s*" /y /q' % (os.path.normpath(src), os.path.normpath(dst)))`.

Comment: normpath return the same path without any escapes

Comment: @eryksun: I think adding an `/i` will prevent `xcopy` from prompting whether the destination is a file or directory.

Comment: `normpath` converts forward slash to backslash for you. xcopy.exe does not work with forward slash in paths, even when quoted. @martineau, `/I` only disambiguates the destination as a directory when copying multiple files; it doesn't help when the target is a file name like in the OP's example.

Comment: r"С:\appFolder\appFile.txt" works!
But i'm using paths in variables... how to achive raw strings in this case?

Comment: I already showed you how to do that. If it's not working, there's something wrong with the paths you have in the variables. Include the printed `repr` of the source and destination paths in your question.

Comment: This works!
`path1 = r'F:\venodor\assets\binkw32.dll'
path2 = r'E:\Work\Update\assets\binkw32.dll'
subprocess.call('xcopy "%s" "%s*" /s /y /q' % (path1, path2))`
But i need
`path1 = cd + folder + filename
path2 =newcd + newfolder + filename
subprocess.call('xcopy "%s" "%s*" /s /y /q' % (path1, path2))`
`os.path.normpath` return the same path without changes...

Comment: Yes, `path1` and `path2` are already normalized, but if they used slash instead of backslash, `normpath` would fix them, which is necessary for xcopy.exe to work correctly. BTW, why are you using `/s` for copying single files? If the source and destination directory are the same, xcopy will fail with `/s`.

Comment: SHEEEEIIIIT!!
`\n` on each line......
solved by `.rstrip()`

Comment: That's why I said we need to see the `repr` of the paths. `normpath` won't remove illegal characters or special names such as trying to create a file named "nul.txt" in Windows (instead it opens the `NUL` device).

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something similar to this, by using sys and env cmds instead?:-

```
import sys,os
PATHTOFILE1="Some_path"
PATHTOFILE2="some other path"
os.environ['PATHTOFILE1'] = PATHTOFILE1
os.environ['PATHTOFILE2'] = PATHTOFILE2
os.system('xcopy "$PATHTOFILE1" "$PATHTOFILE2" /s /y /q >nul')
```

Comment: "$PATHTOFILE1 NOT FOUD"